# react useEffect making the fetch fail

Tags: reactjs, typescript, use-effect

so i have this functional compponent:

```
    function FeedPage() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const globalEvents = useSelector((state: any) => state.events);
  const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://localhost:8080/feed/events", {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: "Bearer " + token,
      },
    })
      .then((res) => {
        return res.json();
      })
      .then((resData) => {
        dispatch(EventsActions.fetchEvents(resData));
        console.log(globalEvents);
        return resData
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="EventList">
      <h1>events</h1>
      {globalEvents &&
        globalEvents.map((event: any) => (
          <div className="event-preview" key={event._id}>
            <h4>{event.eventId.title}</h4>
            <h4>{event.userId}</h4>
          </div>
        ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

and for some reson it return me empty array(when it no supposed to)
but when i do the fetch out side the useEffect hook i get the full array, but i fetch is runing in an infinate loop.
i am new to react btw

Comment: What does reducer look like for the `fetchEvents` action?

Comment: reducers: {
    fetchEvents(state: any, action: any) {
      state.events = action.payload;
    },
  },